# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class Toolbar

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, inflate-exception

I am trying to use `ToolBar` (Lollipop Widget) using `android.support.v7` library.

But while running an app getting an error.

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class Toolbar
```

My main goal is to have a `navigation drawer` using `toolbar`.

This is the Layout file which i am using :

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/frame_container1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >


<Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"            <------ line #7
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/status" ></Toolbar>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF" >

    <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </RelativeLayout>
    <!-- Listview to display slider menu -->

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:dividerHeight=".02dp"        
        android:background="#000000"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>
```

I am using following code :

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new String[]{""});
        //mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
         t=(Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        //getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        //getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);


        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
                R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {

                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                //  invalidateOptionsMenu();
            super.onDrawerClosed(view);
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {


                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    }
```

Please help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar  />
```

instead of

```
<Toolbar  />
```

Comment: I'm getting the exact same error, but I do have `<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar  />` defined in my layout. Any other ideas?

Comment: Never mind. Seems to be working now. I did two things; I'm not sure which one fixed it:

1) I updated the android-support-v13.jar library in my `libs` folder (the one I was using was still from the previous SDK).

2) I changed XML from:

`<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp" />`

to:

`<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp" >
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>`

Comment: Also had this issue and realized after a while that I simply forgot to make MyActivity extend ActionBarActivity instead of Activity. Might help someone