# AppCompat v7 Toolbar "Error inflating class <unknown>"

Tags: android, android-actionbar, toolbar, android-appcompat

I need to use new Toolbar feature introduced in AppCompat V7:21 after reading SO thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26614696/1340311/) and android blog post [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.pt/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html/). I exacctly copied Toolbar snippet from the blogpost to my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar                  <- Line 8
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The problem is that I get :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.blabla.PrefActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class <unknown>
```

Interestingly, if I remove this line:
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"

it works. So the problem is not because of project dependencies or so. It seems I only cannot access ?attr elements like actionBarSize or colorPrimary

Not neede to say that I have already added AppCompat dependency. And the activity is inherited from PreferenceActivity. here's my gradle:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
}
```

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26561235/error-inflating-class-android-support-v7-widget-toolbar/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26463160/android-view-inflateexception-binary-xml-file-line-7-error-inflating-class-to/) people reported to solve the issue on a random basis. But my random didn't work for past two days.

EDIT:

here is my activity:

```
public class PrefActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

private Toolbar mToolbar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) findViewById(android.R.id.content);
    LinearLayout content = (LinearLayout) root.getChildAt(0);
    LinearLayout toolbarContainer = (LinearLayout) View.inflate(this, R.layout.activity_prefs, null);

    root.removeAllViews();
    toolbarContainer.addView(content);
    root.addView(toolbarContainer);

    mToolbar = (Toolbar) toolbarContainer.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    selectResource();
    mToolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha);
    mToolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: con you show your complete layout-file?

Comment: try using `android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"`

Comment: @VipulKumar not only doesn't solve but I need pre API14 compatibility

Comment: I'd rather use `android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"`, if there's no difference for you.

Comment: @miav yes, I would do so too. But I kept the Toolbar snippet exactly the same as the one in the android blog. Once the issue resolved I will add my own attributes.

Comment: Can't help you - code works fine with me also, so the issue is to be found elsewhere.

Comment: @RobinDijkhof yess, question editted

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26708230/where-do-i-define-xml-for-the-toolbar-widget-in-android-5-0

Comment: extend activity instead PreferenceActivity n try....

Comment: As I understand it's not the complete dependencies block of your gradle file. Because I wonder where is 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'

Comment: @VolodymyrBaydalka question editted. Still no clue

Comment: Question #2 - Is application theme set (<application android:theme=...)? And is it inherited from AppCompat themes? Or is activity theme inherited from AppCompat themes?

Comment: @VolodymyrBaydalka thanks buddy. Now works like a charm. As others are suffering from this, please take your time to prepare the answer I vote for it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using of attributes (?attr/) means using of values from theme of current Context. You need to be sure that your theme has value for ?attr/actionBarSize attibute. You can use or inherit your theme from @style/Theme.AppCompat. Or just set value manually.

Comment: I think that dimens is a good solution to size values storing, better than theme atrributs or hardcoded values