# App crashing with InflateException

Tags: android

My app keeps crashing with android.view.InflateException.
Here is my layout file content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <!-- our toolbar -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>



    <!-- our tablayout to display tabs  -->
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        />

    <!-- View pager to swipe views -->
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>


  <!--  <com.csr.audit.adapters.ExpandableHeightGridView
        android:id="@+id/gridviewimg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="3dp"
        android:isScrollContainer="false"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="3dp" /> -->


   </LinearLayout>
```

The above file is supposed to create swipe view with tabs. I have separate fragments for each tab.

Here is the log cat content:

```
03-08 16:17:43.845 9531-9558/com.csr.audit E/Expected Time: 319015163
03-08 16:17:49.734 9531-9531/com.csr.audit E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
     Process: com.csr.audit, PID: 9531
     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.csr.audit/com.csr.audit.AuditForm}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class <unknown>
         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
         at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
      Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class <unknown>
      Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class <unknown>
      Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334)
         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256)
         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
         at com.csr.audit.AuditForm.onCreate(AuditForm.java:148)
         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
         at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
      Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 13: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f01011f a=-1}
         at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawableForDensity(TypedArray.java:944)
         at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:928)
         at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:4768)
         at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:597)
         at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:593)
         at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Toolbar.java:203)
         at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Toolbar.java:199)
         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method) 
         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334) 
         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647) 
         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790) 
         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730) 
         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863) 
         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824) 
         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256) 
         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109) 
         at com.csr.audit.AuditForm.onCreate(AuditForm.java:148) 
         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009) 
         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000) 
         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214) 
         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731) 
         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856) 
         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589) 
         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
         at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

This is the content of values>styles.xml:

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>


    <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.
        -->

    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">

        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    </style>
    <style name="Theme.AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <!-- customize the color palette -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/blue_1</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/blue_1</item>
        <!-- <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>-->
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/primary_text</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/secondary_text</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>





    </style>
    <style name="menu_labels_style">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/fab_label_background</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>

    </style>
    <style name="fade_animation">
        <item name="@android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/popup_show</item>
        <item name="@android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/popup_hide</item>

    </style>

    <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">

        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">#488AC7</item>

    </style>

    <style name="FontTitle" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/primary_text</item>

    </style>

    <style name="FontSubTitle" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/secondary_text</item>

    </style>

    <style name="FontSmall" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/primary_text</item>

    </style>

    <style name="CommentEditTextStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.EditText">

        <item name="android:digits">
            "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890.- "
        </item>
        <item name="android:gravity">left|center_vertical</item>
        <item name="android:padding">16dp</item>


        <item name="android:inputType">textMultiLine|textCapSentences</item>
        <item name="android:maxLength">140</item>
    </style>

    <style name="NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

    </style>

    <style name="AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" >

    </style>

    <style name="PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" >

    </style>
    <style name="AppThemeCompactLight" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/blue_1</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/blue_1</item>

        <item name="colorAccent">@color/silkblue</item>

        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/primary_text</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/secondary_text</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/primary_text</item>


        <!--<item name="android:windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>-->
        <!--<item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/FontSubTitle</item>-->
    </style>
    <style name="MyMaterialTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/blue_1</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/blue_1</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/silkblue</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/primary_text</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/primary_text</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/primary_text</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Can you please tell if this is due to mistake in the way the two layouts
are being used? Please help.
I'm trying to resolve this issue since a week, with no success.
I'll really appreciate your help.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: post your crash log !!

Comment: Yes, added it in the question.

Comment: Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27903000/appcompat-v7-toolbar-error-inflating-class-unknown

Comment: Start debugging. Make an empty pager adapter, run the app, if it dosn't crash, the main layout is OK. And so on. Figure out, which layout in particular is wrong.

Comment: @Massimo: Thanks, but that solution didn't help.

Comment: @Eugen, Thanks a lot, I'll do that.

Comment: @Eugen, the problem is with the main layout for viewpager and tablayout.

Comment: Please post the application theme. According to the stack trace, Toolbar cannot inflate a drawable. The only drawable you specified is the background.

Comment: @Eugen, I added the values>styles.xml file content in the question. Please check it.