# getting Error inflating class Toolbar

Tags: java, android

I am trying to change the action bar properties of my activities but I am getting an error "`Error inflating class toolbar`".
Here is the code snippet :

```
    import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_vendor_details);
    Toolbar toolbar= (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Details");
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Here is the Android Manifest code for that activity :

```
    <activity
        android:name=".VendorDetails"
        android:label="VendorDetails"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>
```

And the layout code for the toolbar is :

```
    <Toolbar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">
</Toolbar>
```

Does anyone know how to solve it?
I am stuck on it since yesterday now. Thanks in advance.

Here is the full xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.example.sachinparashar.omitravendorassistance.Verify"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_verify">


<TextView
    android:layout_width="210dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Enter the Code sent"
    android:id="@+id/verifyText"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/userCode"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
    android:hint="Enter Code"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Verify"
    android:id="@+id/verify"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:textStyle="bold|italic"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/userCode"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:onClick="onVerify" />
<Button
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Resend"
    android:id="@+id/resend"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_below="@+id/verify"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
    android:onClick="onResend"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="700dp"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:id="@+id/timer"
    android:layout_below="@+id/userCode"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class Toolbar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26463160/android-view-inflateexception-binary-xml-file-line-7-error-inflating-class-to)

Comment: Try using `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` in your XML.

Comment: Refer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26504532/appcompat-toolbar-popuptheme-not-used-in-the-shareaction-menuitem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use Toolbar as below in xml.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: Great, it worked. Thank you so much. I was so much frustrated because of it.

Comment: It's working but not acquiring the full width of the screen like the action bar does.

Comment: Where do I get the option to "Accept" the answer? I don't see any.

Comment: Hey, I just copied the toolbar code in my other activity but the setTitle() method is not working for it.

Comment: for my previous activity I didn't setup any TextView for it but still it is working there. And yes, I am using AppCompactActivity.